# Manhwa with a poor girl who is reincarnated as a princess who can see fairies

Tags: story-identification, manga

This was a manhwa I read approximately 2-3 years ago. The main character was a teenaged girl with brown hair who was poor and got caught stealing. She then got reincarnated into a princess who could see fairies.

I also remember she was helping someone with their house too. The father was supposedly feared by others(?).

There was a side character, possibly a prince, who was also a kid and had black hair and wore a mask.

Comment: *[Maiden of the Needle](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Maiden-Needle-Vol-1-Zeroki-ebook/dp/B0C3DVMNH6)*?